# jQuery .find(selector) troubles when selecting ajax.net element

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax.net

I'm trying to find an ajax.net extender element with a dynamically generated ID.  I'm trying to wire up an event handler to close all ajax.net modal popups when 'escape' is pressed.  I'm confused why one of these works and one does not.

```
$find('ctl00_MainContent_ucUserControl1_mpePopup'); //returns the element
$find('[id="ctl00_MainContent_ucUserControl1_mpePopup"]'); //returns null
```

The ultimate goal is to be able to find the element without hard wiring the ID into the selector:

```
$find('[id$="_mpePopup"]');  //return all elements that end with "_mpePopup"
```

Comment: Just FYI: `$find` is a shortcut in MS AJAX; not jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

I see now that there's a difference between $find and .find().  I hadn't realized that, but once it was mentioned that $find() was an MS Ajax shortcut, I looked deeper and found a solution that joins jQuery with MS Ajax.

```
var popups = $.grep(Sys.Application.getComponents(),
                function (elem, index) {
                    return $(elem).attr('_name') == 'ModalPopupBehavior';
                }
            );
$(popups).each(function () { this.hide(); });
```

The issue is $find(id) simply returns the element at Sys.Application._components[id].  'id' is an index in this case, so you can't use a partial string or pattern.

Once you convert that collection into an array though, you can use jQuery.grep() on it to return an array of elements that satisfy some condition (in this case I noticed that '_name' was even easier to use than an attribute selector) and iterate through them with jQuery.each().

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll find that the `$find` operation requires a single ID. Unless I am grossly mistaken, there is no pattern matching capability in it. (For additional information on `$find` and `$get`, see http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/08/the_everuseful_get_and_find_as.html)

You might consider populating a JavaScript variable with the known popup client ID, using the ever-helpful `<%= mpePopup.ClientID %>` page literal binding syntax or some other method convenient to your situation. Below is a simple example of ASPX markup, where `mpePopup` is a member of the page class:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function closePopup() {
        var mpePopupID = '<%= mpePopup.ClientID %>';
        var mpePopupBehavior = $find(mpePopupID);
        // ...
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Imagine a scenario in which many user controls, each with modal popup extenders, are added to the same document.  The idea is to write a single event handler that closes any open modal popups on escape key press from the document level, rather than one handler per user control.  I suppose I could add ClientIDs resolved in the user controls to a global list variable and iterate through it at the document level.... The documentation at http://api.jquery.com/find/ suggests (to me) that standard jQuery selectors should work though.

Comment: @Gabe - please be aware that the jQuery `.find()` method and the MS AJAX `$find` shortcut are very different things. The jQuery method returns a jQuery wrapper around DOM elements, whereas the MS AJAX method finds a single JavaScript component ("behavior"). That said, adding client IDs to a javascript array which you can iterate through on the client side is one workable strategy for closing the popups. I would expect that deriving the solution from the code provided above is quite doable.

Comment: @Gabe: Aha. I see your posted solution. That is a clever method. Bravo.